# Nature of singularities of $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{z})}$

Tags: complex-analysis

What are singularities of $$f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{z})}$$

I can show that the singularities are given by $$\sin(\frac{1}{z})=0=\sin(n\pi)$$

This gives $z=\frac{1}{n},n=0,1,2,3,4....$

Now, how can i say what kind of singularities are these ? like poles, essential singularity or removable singularity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$n=0$ doesn't quite work :) You're also missing $n=-1,-2,-3,\dots$. What does the Laurent series of $f(z)$ look like at $z=\pm 1/n$? (Hint: What kind of zero does $\sin$ have at $\pm \pi n$?)

Be warned, however: $z=0$ is not an isolated singularity of this function.

Comment: ok so finding the laurent series and observinf the principle part is the way right ?

Comment: Absolutely. That's how we understand the nature of an isolated singularity. (You do not need to compute all the terms explicitly, just understand whether there are zero, finitely many, or infinitely many terms with negative exponents.)

Answer (score 1):

$f(z)$ has simple poles at $z_n=±1/n, (n \not = 0)$. $n=0$ is an intrinsic singularity because infinity number of poles $z_n=±1/n,n \to ±\infty$ will all pile on $n=\infty$ or $z=0$.